# Limit multiple joined results to 1, by order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have persons, monsters and vampires, all of which can have multiple files referenced from a files table.
Simplified tables:

```
files:     id, name;
character: id, type;
person:    id, characterId FK character.id;
monster:   id, characterId FK character.id;
vampire:   id, characterId FK character.id;
person_files:  personId FK person.id,   fileId FK file.id, order;
monster_files: monsterId FK monster.id, fileId FK file.id, order;
vampire_files: vampireId FK vampire.id, fileId FK file.id, order;
```

As input I have a character.id. Am trying to get only one file.id while looking up the lowest ordered files in person_files, vampire_files and monster_files.
If person_files returns a result, we're done. Otherwise look up vampire_files and / or monster_files. Should return null if no files are found.

I could do something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM character
LEFT JOIN person ON person.characterId = character.id
LEFT JOIN monster ON monster.characterId = monster.id
LEFT JOIN vampire ON vampire.characterId = monster.id
LEFT JOIN files as f1 ON person.fileID = f1.fileId
LEFT JOIN files as f2 ON monster.fileID = f2.fileId
LEFT JOIN files as f3 ON monster.fileID = f3.fileId
```

and filter out the data with where/min/max etc.

However it seems unnecessary to triple join on the files table when I am just looking up one file.id. Is there a subquery possible to prevent joining so many times and return just one myFileId? Would like to do this as efficiently as possible.

ie

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *one file.id*, MIN(order) as myFileId FROM person/monster/vampire...)
```

Comment: Subqueries are in 99% of cases going to be slower than joins

Comment: If your data model is generic: `character_type` <-- `character` <-- `character_file` --> `file`, the the query will be easier.

Comment: it's a simplified table example, the real tables aren't as generic

Answer (score 0):

One optimization I could think of would be to select one `fileId` value based on which of `person`, `monster` or `vampire` table has a non-null field. The query will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT COALESCE(person.file_id, monster.file_id, vampire.file_id) AS realFileId
  FROM character
  LEFT JOIN person ON person.characterId = character.id
  LEFT JOIN monster ON monster.characterId = monster.id
  LEFT JOIN vampire ON vampire.characterId = monster.id
) x
LEFT JOIN files f 
ON x.realFileId=f.fileId
```

If you want to make life simpler for yourself, you may also consider adding a `characterType` field to `character` table and use it together with CASE operator to determine which table you need to join:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT COALESCE(person.file_id, monster.file_id, vampire.file_id) AS realFileId
  FROM character
  LEFT JOIN person ON person.characterId = character.id 
    AND character.characterType="person"
  LEFT JOIN monster ON monster.characterId = monster.id
    AND character.characterType="monster"
  LEFT JOIN vampire ON vampire.characterId = monster.id
    AND character.characterType="vampire"
) x 
LEFT JOIN files f 
ON x.realFileId=f.fileId
```

While this looks more complex than the previous version, the optimizer in this case should optimize away the joins you won't be using (since you'll be literally joining on `FALSE`) and thus speed up the query quite a bit.